# Module functions after bundle with Webpack aren't recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, webpack

I'm trying to bundle my node.js project into one single file, which would contain all the modules that it needs, by using webpack. 
After creating a `bundle.js` file, I cannot run it because some functions from required modules are not recognized:

In the `Server.js` file I had required `'http'` , and used `http.createServer()` function.

When I'm running the file, it says: `TypeError: r.createServer is not a function`


How can I bundle the project with all of it's modules correctly?

Relevant parts of my `Package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run lint && jasmine",
    "lint": "sh util/lintRunner.sh",
    "fix": "sh util/lintFixer.sh",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist/"
  }
```

My `webpack.comfig.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './Server/Server.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        dns: 'empty'
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Webpack with nodejs on the backend? Building a single smaller bundle only makes sense for the frontend.

Comment: Try adding `target: 'node'` to your configuration.

Comment: @squgeim Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @squgeim can you add your answer as an answer?

Comment: @goofballLogic done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell WebPack where your bundled javascript is going to run; in this case in a nodejs environment.

Try adding `target: 'node'` to your configuration.

Read more about the `target` attribute: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/